# Scala: Math functions not methods

Tags: scala

Is there an object with the normal mathematical functions as *function values* in scala?

I am pretty new to Scala, and find it a little sad that `scala.math` defines *methods*, which adds a some unnecessary `(  _)` clutter to produce first class functions. For example:

```
[tuple code] (min _).tupled  [more code]
[curry code] (min _).curried [more code]
```

It would be cleaner like this

```
[tuple code] min.tupled  [more code]
[curry code] min.curried [more code]
```

or even just:

```
[tuple code] min [more code]
[curry code] min [more code]
```

**Edit:** Some more concrete examples as requested:

```
Seq((1, 2), (3, 4)) map (min _).tupled

val a = 1 to 4; val b = a.reverse
val c = a.view zip b map (min _).tupled

val negative = (min _).curried (0)
```

Comment: Can you make a more specific example? What is `[more code]`, `[tuple code]` and `[curry code]`? Also: You could store the function object in a value first, e.g., `val min = scala.math.min _; min.tupled`

Comment: Sure. I have put some more examples up there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing that I'm aware of, but it would be trivial to achieve this by yourself

```
object MathFunctions {
  import math._
  val minF = min _
  val maxF = max _
  // ...
}
import MathFunctions._

Seq((1, 2), (3, 4)) map minF.tupled
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to just copy and modify `scala.math`, which revealed the reason why `scala.math` use methods: **Overloading**. You can have multiple methods with the same name, but not multiple function values. To get around this you would probably need to use implicits, which makes it all a little more cumbersome.

Comment: I can think of two solutions to the name-ambiguity (overloading) issue: Either name the functions differently (e.g. `val imin: (Int, Int) => Int = min; val dmin: (Double, Double) => Double = min; ...`) or scope the min-functions: `object MathFunctions{ object IntegerFunctions{...} object DoubleFunctions{...}...}`. Also: If you add `implicit def function2ToTupledFunction[A, B, C](function: (A, B) => C): ((A, B)) => C = function.tupled` and `implicit def function2ToCurriedFunction[A, B, C](function: (A, B) => C): (A) => (B) => C = function.curried`, you can get rid of `.tupled` / `.curried`.